# Sudden MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure what I did to my MySQL install but after running perfectly for years and recently migrating over to Snow Leopard (and working fine for about a month or more) MySQL generates errors for both Rails 2 and 3 apps (I don't use MySQL for anything else).

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/x/Sites/subscriptions)
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _mysql_real_connect
  Referenced from: /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle - /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysqlplus-0.1.2/lib/mysql.bundle
/Users/x/Sites/subscriptions/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It's been this way for over a few days now and it's really starting to be an issue. Any clue what might be causing this? I think I may have to recompile MySQL via macports but I'm not sure if that will actually do the trick or cause more issues. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not an answer, but a thought only: I would suggest you forget about mysql and go straight to sqlite. I find mysql to be a little overkill most of the times, at least for development - unless you need some scalability which sqlite can't offer (which you probably don't)

Comment: Unfortunately I use some gems/plugins (such as geokit) which require the use of specific functions not present in sqlite. I WISH I could use only sqlite though! Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Snow Leopard and everything went to hell in my ruby environment. Here are my suggestions:

Before you do anything, make sure you have an up-to-date version of gcc.
Ditch macports - homebrew is a much better package management tool and results in almost no errors.
Reinstall your base ruby and then reinstall rvm

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling mysql entirely, but I would bet that your ruby got corrupted. SL introduced some major architecture changes that cause bizarre errors everywhere (I had insane errors with postgres, http, and other unfun things)

Comment: I'll give this a shot. These kind of changes give me quivers to even think about but I guess it has to be done. Thanks for the suggestions. Will try them!

Answer (score 0):

Been there. It could be you are running a 64 bit while MySQL is still 32. Try what Anthony suggested and keep an eye on the bit version

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. Thanks for the input!